# Call non action method from View

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I have a method in that I am having a date picker control, on that selection I want to bind the data to the same view.

So, I wanted to call non action method for `onchange` event of date using `ajax()`, but could not do it.

Can anyone help me with this?

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult GetCall()
    {
        return View();
    }
[NonAction]
    public JsonResult GetData(int currentMonth)
    {
        var data= object.datacall(currentMonth);
        return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

ajax call:-

```js
$.ajax({
    url: 'GetData',
    method: 'GET',
    data: { 'currentMonth': date.getMonth()},
    success: function (data) { },
    error: function (response) { }
});
```

Comment: Remove the `[NonAction]` attribute

Comment: Also read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6385599/asp-net-mvc-nonaction-meaning) to understand usage of `NonActionAttribute`.

Comment: yes i can call it by removing [NonAction], but now it is invocable from URL

Comment: Then use an [AjaxOnly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23900411/mvc-set-accessibility-level-on-a-method-called-from-ajax/23900475#23900475) attribute.

Comment: Yes that sounds good, thank you @StephenMuecke